# Keyboard backlight on GNOME?

Tags: debian, xorg, gnome-shell, keyboard-backlight

I have an Asus VivoBook S510U running Debian buster/sid with GNOME 3.28.2 and still using XORG. A couple of months ago I was able to use the function keys to change keyboard backlight and I was also able to change that setting with a slider on the power screen.

Now I don't see the slider anymore and the function keys show the OSD of the keyboard backlight but they don't change anything.
Can't remember the exact update that caused this.

I'm able to change the brightness using this command:

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Echoing from 0 to 3 to get different brightness.

I understand that I can make this into a script and set a hotkey to it, but I'd like to get the previous behaviour working that also showed the slider.

Any hint on how to do that?